# succes function in ajax call depends on echo from PDO

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

i need to customize the success message in an ajax call based on the result after inserting data into mysql table,

```
 $.ajax({
             data: dataString,
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'mypage.php',
             success: function(data)
             {
                 if (data === 'success') {
                    alert("New record created successfull");
                 }else{alert("something goes wrong"); }
             }
            });
```

here is the php code

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
// use exec() because no results are returned
$conn->exec($sql);
echo "success";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "fail";
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

and when i try to check the message returned from the php page i get the right alert with this ajax call

```
$.ajax({
             data: dataString,
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'mypage.php',
             success: function(data)
             {
                 alert(data);
             }
            });
```

i tried many things but i cannot find where is the problem exactly, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to check 'success' against "data" not "response"

Comment: i made a mistake here, it is data instead of response in my code

Comment: Also, you might want to set `dataType: 'text',` before `success: function(data)` to tell your function you are receiving plain text.

Comment: not working event with dataType i get always the else statement even when the message is success,

Comment: data: dataString , where Is dataString defined?

Comment: i have a var with serialized forms in top of the ajax call

Comment: Its hard to guess what the problem is if we don't know the response. Probably your script is throwing some errors and thus your data cannot be 'success'. Best you install web developer tools for your browser [For chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and see what you get when you look into the network tab and see the response your server/script sends. This will be extremely helpful for you anyway not only for this problem.

Comment: I ve tried all these things before asking this question, the only thing that I cannot understand and don't make any sense, that when I use alert (data); to print the result from the PHP I can get the right message success if the data is inserted and fail if there is a problem of inserting data into mysql table, but when I use if statement to customise the message it don't work and I get always the else statement like if the success function don't read the "success" text sent from the PHP page. it makes me crazy.

Comment: I have just tried following `$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: 'data=1&some=name',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 'success') {
                    alert('Success returned :)');
                } else {
                    alert('Error returned :(');
                }
            }
        });` while test.php contains `<?php echo 'success';` and once  `<?php echo 'fail';` And it works fine in both cases.. dont know any further mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work I used same code in another case:

```
if ($.trim(data) === 'success') {
   alert("New record created successfull");
}else{alert("something goes wrong"); }
```

Comment: i ve tried 2 equal signs instead of 3 but always i get the alert of fail, am really confused i don't know why when i use alert(data); i get the success or fail message from php page, while this don't work when i add an if statement.

Comment: You can use 3 === signs actually. Did you change result to data as shown above?

Comment: like i ve said in my code i have data and not a response it is a mistake only here

Comment: try trimming any possible whitespaces with this $.trim(data);

Comment: bryangators55 I don't know how or where there is a white space, but something that I know it well you're genius, it works finally!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! post this into a answer that i can confirm it as a solution and thank one more time